# Why don't I get an Array from a NSKeyedUnarchiver?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedarchiver

Here is my Code :

```
NSString * path = kCachePath(kCacheFileName);
NSMutableArray * arry = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
arry = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];

//    NSData * data  = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:path];
//    NSError *error = nil;
//    arry = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];

if (arry) {
    [arry addObject:playModel];
    NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arry];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:data toFile:path];
    return YES;
} else {
    NSMutableArray * ary = [NSMutableArray array];
    [ary addObject:playModel];
    NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:ary];
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:data toFile:path];
}
```

I have successfully archived an array to the file, but when I want to unwrap the data file, I got an `NSMutableData', But I want an`NSMutableArray`. and I have tried the`NSJSONSerialization`to conver the`NSdata`to`NSMutableArray`and I got a`nil`. any one knows where goes wrong?

and here is my cachePath:

```
#define kCacheFileName @"fakeLiveHistory.data"
#define kCachePath(kCacheFileName) ([NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kCacheFileName])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you ARCHIVE data - not an array so obviously next time you get data back ;)

archive the array as a start

```
    NSData * data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arry];

    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:data toFile:path];
```

-->

```
    [NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:arry toFile:path];
```